# I'm back! With a film recommendation

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, movies

*Wow*, it's been a long time since I posted a puzzle here... Sorry about that!

I asked a friend the other day what was his favourite film, but he'd reply only in riddles. I don't remember how he described the film as a whole, but about the first half he said:

> I look small, but am vast.
> A fireball, but in the past.

And about the second half:

> In the air you barely see me.
> You do me to get rid of me.

And about the middle:

> A blue box from elsewhere,
> But you, not I, go there.

**What was the name of the film?**

---

> **Note:** you should be able to solve this without knowing anything about the film in question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The recommended film is

> [Stardust](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stardust_(2007_film)) - a film based on Neil Gaiman's novel, with a famous cast. (Unless OP means a 70's musical with David Essex!)

First half: I look small, but am vast. A fireball, but in the past.

> Seen from a distance, stars look tiny, in reality huge. The light we see has taken a long time to arrive.

Second half: In the air you barely see me. You do me to get rid of me.

> It's hard to see dust until it settles. Then dust to remove dust.

The middle: A blue box from elsewhere, But you, not I, go there.

> The Tardis is the blue police box from Doctor Who. Then switch i to u.

Comment: ah... nice, would like this to be the answer!

Comment: Yep, you got it. Good job.

Answer (score 3):

Partial:

First Part:

> **Sun**

Explanation:

> look small: in human eyes
>  but am vast: in reaity
> A fireball, but in the past: the sun was like a fireball

Comment: My 100th answer, devoted to RandAlThor, our mighty senpai!

Comment: Not quite right, I'm afraid.

Comment: Grats on the 100 answers! :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor am i near at least? is it rot13(fgne)? thanks!